# Panda Columns are Inexplicable Reversed

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

This question may be a little obscure.  (Note: I am using python's Pandas library to extract some text data from .csv files.  I know that Pandas wasn't built for text, but I find it's far more intuitive than the `csv` lib.)

Here's my problem.

I have two files -- files A & B -- each with three columns, which appear in the exact same order in the csv files themselves.  The columns are X, Y, & Z.

```
colnames = ['X', 'Y','Z']
data = pandas.read_csv('C:...path...\File_A.csv', names=colnames)

col_x = list(data.X)
col_y = list(data.Y)
col_z = list(data.Z)
```

When I open and print the contents of `File_B` (i.e., placing `File_B` in the `read_csv` line instead of `File_A`), columns `col_x` & `col_y` are reversed.  In other words, if I print each col_x item for File_A, it shows the contents of col_x, but when I print col_x for File_B it shows the contents of col_y.

The columns are inexplicably reversed, and this is stopping me from abstracting the problem I'm trying to solve, since I have to change the scripts' functionality depending on which file I open.  Does anyone know why X & Y would be reversed in the different files?  The csv files themselves have the exact same column order -- `X,Y,Z` -- so I believe the problem is in the Pandas library or my script.  Any help would be hugely appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the colname = ['X', 'Y', 'Y'] just a typo in your post?

Comment: @chrisb yes, I'm an idiot.  thank you for catching that.

Comment: why don't you just grab the names from the csv file itself? also, you should double check your input

Comment: You will have to show some more info if you want to get an answer. Trry to reproduce it with a small example, show the contents of both files and `data.info()` of both dataframes, ..